# With a hash of lists how do I operate on each key/list element once in random order?

Tags: algorithm, perl

For example, if my HoL looks like:

```
%HoL = ( 
    "flintstones"        => [ "fred", "barney" ],
    "jetsons"            => [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
    "simpsons"           => [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
);
```

And I want to create a loop that will allow me to operate *only once* on each key/element pair in a completely random order (so that it jumps between keys randomly too, not just elements), how do I do that?  I'm thinking it will use shuffle, but figuring out the specifics is defeating me.

(Sorry for noobishness of question; I haven't been coding long.  I was also unable to find an answer for this specific problem by googling, though I daresay it's been answered somewhere before.)

Comment: Take the list returned by `keys %HoL`, shuffle it, then use its members to access the values.

Comment: The way you're describing it, I don't think this works.  I can shuffle the keys easily enough, and then shuffle the values in the array attached to each key, but how do I get a randomised list of every possible key/element pair?


So for example the resulting sets of k/v's might look like:
(k,v)
flintstones->[0], simpsons->[2], jetsons->[1], jetsons->[0], simpsons->[1], etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build an array of all key-value pairs, then shuffle that:

```
use List::Util 'shuffle';

my %HoL = (
    "flintstones"        => [ "fred", "barney" ],
    "jetsons"            => [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
    "simpsons"           => [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
);

# Build an array of arrayrefs ($ref->[0] is the key and $ref->[1] is the value)
my @ArrayOfPairs = map {
  my $key = $_;
  map { [ $key, $_ ] } @{$HoL{$key}}
} keys %HoL;


for my $pair (shuffle @ArrayOfPairs) {
  print "$pair->[1] $pair->[0]\n";
}
```